# Linear Operators on $L_2(\mathbb R)$ definfed as Integrals

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let's consider the linear operators on $L_2(\mathbb R)$

$$
T_{\alpha}f(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{e^{-|x-y|^2}}{(1+x^2)^{\alpha}}f(y)dy
$$

with ${\alpha} \in [0,1]$.

Find ${\alpha}$ such that $T_{\alpha}$ is continuous. Find at least one value of ${\alpha}$ for which $T_{\alpha}$ is compact, and one for which it is not compact.

To show the continuity I would like to show that they are bounded, but I don't know how. In order to show compactness we know that if $\frac{e^-{|x-y|^2}}{(1+x^2)^{\alpha}}$ is in $L_2(\mathbb R^2)$ the operator is compact.

Thanks!

Comment: Notice that $T_0$ is a convolution operator and $$ e^{-x^2}\in\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})\subset L^2(\mathbb{R}).$$

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio so since $\frac{1}{(1+x^2)^{\alpha}}  \leq 1$, $T_{\alpha}f \leq 1 \cdot |e^{t^{-2}}|_1|f(t)|_2=\sqrt(\pi)|f(t)|_2$ and thus is bounded right? How to find a compact one and a not comact one? Thank you!